# Compiling Hadoop 2.7.1 on ARM (Raspbian)

Tags: maven, hadoop, arm

I am currently trying to compile Hadoop 2.7.1 on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 7 (wheezy) to get the native libraries going. I got most of the dependencies working, but I get the following error from Maven:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) @ hadoop-common ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
 [exec] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
 [exec] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
 [exec] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
 [exec] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
 [exec] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 [exec] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
 [exec] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
 [exec] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
 [exec] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
 [exec] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
 [exec] Soft-float JVM detected
 [exec] -- Looking for exit
 [exec] CMake Error at JNIFlags.cmake:59 (message):
 [exec]   Soft-float dev libraries required (e.g.  'apt-get install libc6-dev-armel'
 [exec]   on Debian/Ubuntu)
 [exec] Call Stack (most recent call first):
 [exec]   CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec] -- Looking for exit - not found.
 [exec] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Obviously it is not as simple as doing the apt-get install libc6-dev-armel that is suggested. This package is not available. However I am unsure as how to proceed. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this going by integrating a patch found in their Jira.

```
cd hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src
wget https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12570212/HADOOP-9320.patch
patch < HADOOP-9320.patch
```

You can find [the relevant page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9320) on their issue tracker.

Comment: I took the time to fully describe the steps I took [here](http://www.becausewecangeek.com/native-hadoop-for-armv7/)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the PATCH 9320 help. But there's many other issues that you can met. We spend a couples of days to compile it. If you want, you can download our compiled hadoop native ARMv7L libs here : http://www.minibig.io/miniblog/2015/10/12/hadoop-271-native-libs-compiled-for-arm